# Remain 10 dollars

Tags: verbs

Can I say: "My debt remained by ten dollars" after paying some part of my debt? I mean can I use "by" in this structure as is the case with the structure "increase by"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that sounds unnatural.

You could say any of the following instead:

> My debt remained ***at*** ten dollar.
>   Ten dollars ***of*** my debt (remained / was remaining).
>   The remainder ***of*** my debt was ten dollars.
>   All ***but*** ten dollars ***of*** my debt (had been / was) paid.

Comment: Thanks. But I could not understood why “ by “ can not be used here. Couldn’t “ by “be  used in the meaning of “as much as “.

Comment: Because as far as I know “ by “ can be used to show degree or amount of something.

Comment: @Foreignstudent You could say *my debt was reduced by ten dollars* but that would not mean the same thing. That would indicate an amount taken away—not the amount that is left over.

Answer (score -2):

'My debt is/was still due by 10 dollars.' sounds more appropriate or 'I still owed him/her/them 10 dollars'.